# Filter key/values in a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Assuming a list of dicts:

```
[{'a':3434,'b':23424,'c':3231,'d':24334243},
{'a':344,'b':234,'c':321,'d':24334}
{'a':34,'b':2424,'c':31,'d':2434243},...]
```

Is there a one-liner way to filter the list getting the dictionaries only with certain keys ['a','b']?

for instance:

```
Result = [{'a':3434,'b':23424},
{'a':344,'b':234}
{'a':34,'b':2424},...]
```

Note: my current solution is with for loops, totally un-elegant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be my homemade approach.

```
newLst = [{k:v for k,v in dicts.items() if k in ['a','b']}for dicts in last]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [{'a':3434,'b':23424,'c':3231,'d':24334243},{'a':344,'b':234,'c':321,'d':24334},{'a':34,'b':2424,'c':31,'d':2434243}]

r = []
for i in a:
    if ('a' in i) and ('b' in i):
        r.append({'a':i['a'], 'b':i['b']})

print(r)
```

output

```
[{'a': 3434, 'b': 23424}, {'a': 344, 'b': 234}, {'a': 34, 'b': 2424}]
```